# adb root "error device not found"

Tags: adb, root, device

### Heading

I have rooted my andriod phone and installed CM11. now /system became readonly. I am not able to install any apps. google services keep crashing.

I am trying to change permission to rw.

## adb root

error: device not found.

Please help me to gain rw access to /system

Tried the same with ES file ex. getting error. "sorry. test failed" errors.

Answer (score 0):

First go in settings and make sure USB debugging is enabled.
Then try this:

```
adb shell
```

or if you are not conected to the device do

```
adb connect ip_of_android
```

(example adb connect 192.168.0.100 )

after you connected to the android do :

```
adb shell
```

to get shell into the device.
Then try to do a

```
mount -o remount,rw /system /system
```

to remount /system read write